# What is the golang structure corresponding to `time` type in mysql?

Tags: mysql, go

I have a mysql table that stores scheduled tasks like an alarm clock.

The representation is designed like this:

**In mysql:**

```
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS `tasks`
(
    //....other fields
    `start_time`  timestamp NOT NULL ,
    `end_time`    timestamp NOT NULL ,
)
```

**In golang:**

```golang
type Tasks struct {
    //....other fields
    StartTime  time.Time `json:"start_time" xorm:"start_time"`
    EndTime    time.Time `json:"end_time" xorm:"end_time"`
}
```

What I want to ask is suppose I change the `tasks` table in mysql to look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS `tasks`
(
    //....other fields
    `start_time`  time NOT NULL ,
    `end_time`    time NOT NULL ,
)
```

How should my `Tasks` structure be designed in Golang?

The reason WHY I want to change `timestamp` to `time` is that I only need the time, not the date information.

Any good suggestions?

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: Why is that?How can I highlight those two fields without using images?@Volker

Comment: @ClancyZeng try using [`pgtype.Time`](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/time.go), although it is a PostgreSQL specific implementation, it seems to me that the MySQL time type representation is compatible with PostgreSQL's.

Comment: @ClancyZeng one way to "highlight" the two fields is to simply remove all the fields that are irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to change `StartTime` and `EndTime` to `[]byte` and parse this yourself to get a `time.Time` type.

You could do something like:

```
type sqlTime []byte
func (s sqlTime) Time() (time.Time, error) {
    return time.Parse("15:04:05",string(s))
}
```

Comment: Like this?

```
type Tasks struct {
    //....other fields
    StartTime  sqlTime `json:"start_time" xorm:"start_time"`
    EndTime    sqlTime `json:"end_time" xorm:"end_time"`
}
```

Comment: that should work and if you want to use it as a time type, just call the sqlTime.Time()

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will consider using your answer if there is no better way.